# Listview, XML. nullpointerexception

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have a trouble in this issue and I cant go forward, stucked for almost 2 days now.

This is what i want Photos is below
[Photo 1 http://leyth.dk/upload/server/php/files/Activity%202.png](http://leyth.dk/upload/server/php/files/Activity%202.png)  [Photo 1 http://leyth.dk/upload/server/php/files/picture%201.png](http://leyth.dk/upload/server/php/files/picture%201.png)

I have json list, and its working fine.when I press the --> **ITEM NUMBER X** it starts the new activity normally, it shows the map with the given lat and long values

But i want too get more values via the list into the 2.activity.

This what I can imagine is i have problem with XML files, maybe inflating or sth like that. i putting some codes so u can see it.

```
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_LAT, TAG_LNG, TAG_POSTAL }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();      
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();


    --> here is fail, it cant find textview1 --> gives null pointer exception 
--> its different xml file. And here is the error appers
            String mandag = ((TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
            String tirsdag = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).getText().toString();
            String onsdag = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3)).getText().toString();
            String torsdag = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4)).getText().toString();
            String fredag = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5)).getText().toString();
            String lordag = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6)).getText().toString();
            String sondag = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView7)).getText().toString();


            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dk.mitaffald.maps.MainActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_LAT, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_LNG, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_Company, description);

            in.putExtra(TAG_MONDAY, mandag);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TUESDAY, tirsdag);
            in.putExtra(TAG_WEDNESDAY, onsdag);
            in.putExtra(TAG_THURSDAY, torsdag);
            in.putExtra(TAG_FRIDAY, fredag);
            in.putExtra(TAG_SATURDAY, lordag);
            in.putExtra(TAG_SUNDAY, sondag);

            Log.d(TAG, "Leyth Days = Mandag : " + mandag +"     Onsdag : " + fredag);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

Here is the logcat

```
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980): java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at dk.mitaffald.main.LocationBased$1.onItemClick(LocationBased.java:188)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3763)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1936)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    02-27 10:55:28.441: E/AndroidRuntime(10980):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**XML File for Textview1**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<fragment 
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Post xml code in which textView1.

Comment: i have just update it.

Answer (score 0):

As what I understand is,

Your **list_item.xml** file for list item row not contains, textView1 , textView2.. etc.. TextViews.

I think these TextViews are from your Activity's xml layout file.

If yes then You have to define these **TextViews** in `onCreate()` of your Activity or Fragment, and directly use, in `onItemClick()` of `ListView`,

Problem of **NullPointerException** Because,

```
String mandag = ((TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
```

You are referring **textView1** from view which is View of List Item row so it cause `NPE`. (And View means `list_item.xml` doesn't contain `textView1`)

Comment: hmm yea but Iam not sure how I will do it, I mean should I do this in the class where is listview?

Comment: Yes, Where you get ListView in the same method define TextViews.

Comment: Yes i can see it now but how I should define it? its not already defined   

String mandag = ((TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
     here?

Comment: Now, in onItemClick() use it like,  `String mandag = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();` remove `view.`

Comment: its giving me still NPE on same line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25215/discussion-between-leyth-hisham-and-user370305)

Answer (score 0):

By using getText().toString() you are getting text. Please check that text is null or not.

Comment: text is not null, becuase there is some sometext in textview